# Sort based on collect value in neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I am having this query `MATCH (r:Class {Name: 'A'})-[perm]->(res:source) RETURN res.Name AS resource, collect(type(perm)) AS permission ORDER BY resource`

It returns me a response like this

```
"AB sources",
      [
        "D",
        "C",
        "A",
        "B"
      ]
```

What I want is that this D C A B should be sorted like A B C D

I tried putting order by for perm but that gives error. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to use the APOC library to sort the collection:

```
MATCH (r:Class {Name: 'A'})-[perm]->(res:source) 
WITH res.Name AS resource, collect(type(perm)) AS permission
RETURN resource, apoc.coll.sort(permission) AS permission
ORDER BY resource
```

Comment: This is indeed sorting permission but now I have lost the sort order of resource
Can both be sorted?